# how to i give a Microsoft Azure voice a different style?

Tags: python, azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I'm having troubles figuring out how to apply different voice styles to the `Microsoft Azure` text to speech voices.

```
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
# Note: the voice setting will not overwrite the voice element in input SSML.
speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name = "en-US-DavisNeural" 
speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_style = "shouting"


text = "Hi, this is Davis"


# use the default speaker as audio output.
speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config)

result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()
```

I`ve tried looking for other guides but some have been taken down and the offical documentation isn`t really help me.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this code? What have you tried to do to fix it, and where are you getting stuck? Does adjusting the value of the string variable `speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_style` not do what you expect? See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

To apply different voice styles to Microsoft Azure Text to Speech voices, you can use Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML).
In your case, you can modify the `text` variable to include SSML tags.

Below is an example of how to apply the `"shouting"` and some other styles using `SSML`:

```py
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk


speech_key = "<API Key>"
service_region = "<Region Code>"

speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)

text = """
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xml:lang="en-US">
    <voice name="en-US-DavisNeural">
        <mstts:express-as style="cheerful" styledegree="2">
            That'd be just amazing!
        </mstts:express-as>
        <mstts:express-as style="shouting" styledegree="2">
            Hi, this is Davis
        </mstts:express-as>
        <mstts:express-as style="sad" styledegree="2">
            What's next?
        </mstts:express-as>
    </voice>
</speak>
"""

speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config)
result = speech_synthesizer.speak_ssml_async(text).get()
output_file = "output.wav"
if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
    audio_data = result.audio_data
    with open(output_file, "wb") as file:
        file.write(audio_data)
    print(f"Audio saved to {output_file}")
```

With the above code snippet, you'll able to get different voice style output.
For more details and examples please check [Customize voice and sound with SSML Documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup-voice)